# Replace "\'" with any other character with String's replace()

Tags: java, string, replace, special-characters

I can't do a simple operation with String, replace \' with *.

Example: `t'est\'` -> `t'est*`

I have tried with replace and replaceAll methods:

String s has the value:  `"t'est\'"`;

```
s.replaceAll("\'", "*"); -> result: t*est*
s.replaceAll("\\'", "*"); -> result: t*est*
s.replaceAll("\\\'", "*"); -> result: t*est*
s.replaceAll("\\\\'", "*"); -> result: t'est'

s.replace("\'", "*"); -> result: t'est'
s.replace("\\'", "*"); -> result: t'est'
s.replace("\\\'", "*"); -> result: t'est'
s.replace("\\\\'", "*"); -> result: t'est'
```

But I don't get the result t'est* in any case.

Comment: Did you write the string in your IDE, or did you print it to see what it was? At which point did it look like t'est\' to you? This matters because of number of \ escapes there are in it.

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure of the value of `s`? `'` isn't a meaningful escape character, so if you write `String s = "t'est\'"`, the value of `s` will just be `"t'est'"`. To include the additional `\` character, you need to escape it by writing `String s = "t'est\\'"`. Then, I think `"\\\\'"` would be the regular expression to use to find it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, String s is initialized with s = "t'est\'" in each line. The problem is that I cant't modify s, because is part of a sql query that I get from a server...

Comment: @user3057179 If you see in console this string: `t'est\'`, then in java file it should be written as follows: String s="t\'est\\\'"; or String s="t'est\\'";

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
String s="t\'est\\\'";
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\'", "*");
System.out.println(s);
```

produces:

```
t'est*
```

I escaped your string with http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html

Comment: The problem is that I have a query to insert into database, and I need to replace \' with '' (double single quote), so I cant do that.

Comment: How about using: StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html), or something similar - it appears to be deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`\'` is actually an escaped `'`.
If you want to have an actual \' you need to escape the slash, namely write `\\\'`

Then you will need to replace it by `\\\\'`. In this case each pair of slashes results to a single escaped slash `\` for java and the resulting `\\'` is a `\'` for regex.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
String s = "t'est\\'";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replace("\\", "*").replace("*'", "*"));
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
t'est\'
t'est*
```

Let me know if my understanding is not correct or if it needs modifications.

Comment: Looks like the straightforward answer!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to escape '
Just write

```
s.replace("'", "*");
```

to replace a '

---

Edit:

If you want to match \' you should try

```
s.replace("\\'", "*");
```

The first Backslash will escape the second, and the ' will remain "unescaped"

Comment: The result should be `t'est*` not `t*est*`. Your solution will replace both `'`

Comment: Result should be `t'est*`

Comment: No it will be t*est*.

Comment: Sorry, i thought he added the Backslash because he wanted to escape the '

Answer (score 0):

When you say that String s has the value "t'est\'" do you mean that's how it appears in the source?  Because, if so, the string you're working with as 's' is actually "t'est'" which means you will never find a "\'" to replace.

If it's declared as "t'est\'", then it will have "\'" in it.

Comment: I have this word in a text file with sql statements.